# jQuery animate() expanding DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I am not an expert in jQuery (and to be honest, I am taking my first steps).

I have the example below, and what I am trying to do is choose the direction of the expansion of my `div`. I am using `animate()` and expanding the `width` and `height`.

At the moment it is expanding to the right, but I want it to change it, so it would expand to the left. The only way I could make the `div` expand to the left, is to add `float: right;` in the CSS of `#map` element.

I want it to know if there is another way to get to this, without changing the `float` of `#map`.

***[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c29rs9y3/12/)***.

***Snippet:***

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#expand').click(function (expandir) {
        this.value = 'collapse';
        if ($(this).data('name') === 'show') {
            $('#map').animate({ width: '600', height: '400' });
            $('#inside').animate({ width: '600', height: '336' });
            $('#expand').animate({ top: '370' });
            $(this).data('name', 'hide');
        } else {
            this.value = 'expand';
            $('#map').animate({ width: '300', height: '250' });
            $('#inside').animate({ width: '300', height: '169' });
            $('#expand').animate({ top: '220' });
            $(this).data('name', 'show');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#map {
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 250px;
    border: 1px solid;
}
#expand {
    z-index: 4;
    position: absolute;
    top: 220px;
    left: 10px;
    width: 70px;
    height: 25px;
}
#inside {
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #000000;
    width: 300px;
    height: 169px;
    background-size: 220px 170px;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#close {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    background-color: #34FF56;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    background-size: 220px 170px;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#btn {
    z-index: 3;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin: 2px;
    background-color: #FF9834;
    width: 70px;
    height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="map">
    <input type="button" data-name="show" value="expand" id="expand" />
    <div id="inside"></div>
    <div id="btn"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wouldn't expanding to **left** would expand beyond the left borders of the viewport and take your button with it?

Comment: Perhaps try moving the box to the left as you expand its width? It will appear to expand to the left, even though it is technically expanding to the right

Comment: @MarcoCordeiro: [This is a solution I had in mind](http://jsfiddle.net/c29rs9y3/14/) in terms of animation the expansion towards the `left` side and hence, clipping occurs. And I think this is exactly what @ConnorS is also referring to.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the positioning inside #map to absolute and add right:??%.The percentage works off the 100% in body tag. Hope this helps for what you need :}

```
#map {
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    height: 250px;
    border: 1px solid;
    right: 50%;
}
```